# OData Feed URL string query filters - Excel Power Query - date does not work

Tags: excel-formula, odata, filtering

I'm trying to use the date as a filter on an OData feed in Power Query Excel. However, I still get all rows from the data set. I don't want to use filters in power query to narrow my data set because this pulls the entire table data and it is too large. I want to use the OData Feed URL source.

Here is what I have. I imagine it is just syntax.

= OData.Feed("https://test-uat.ProjectDate gt datetime'2017-08-08T00:00:00'")

[Results that are incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEBcJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the syntax. OData V4 Conventions stipulate datetime function is not used and the date time value does not have to be enclosed in single quotes. As follows;

filter=ProjectDate gt 2017-08-08T00:00:00Z